# echarts4r plot low resolution in quarto revealjs

Tags: r, quarto

Why are plots done via {echarts4r} blurry in quarto revealjs presentations?

How can this be fixed?

An example:

````
---
title: "Habits"
author: "John Doe"
format: revealjs
---

## Getting up

```{r}
library(echarts4r)
cns <- countrycode::codelist$country.name.en
cns <- data.frame(
country = cns,
value = runif(length(cns), 1, 100)
)

cns |> 
e_charts(country) |> 
e_map(value) |> 
e_visual_map(value)
```


## Going to sleep

- Get in bed
- Count sheep
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably because echart4r plots using [canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) by default which may scale badly (although it looks halfway decent to me for this example).

A remedy is to switch to SVG. You may adjust the parent container using `height` and `width` to fit the plot to the slide.

```
## Running Code

cns |> 
  e_charts(country, width = 1100, height = 550, 
           renderer = "svg") |> 
  e_map(value) |> 
  e_visual_map(value)
```

[image]